# Selecting New Element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery/javascript and have a rather basic question. Why doesn't this work? Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('<div/>', {
                    id: 'foo',
                    text: 'Does not work'
                }).appendTo('body');       });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#foo").click(function () {
                alert('Success'); });
</script>
```

Comment: Your second piece of code isn't in a document ready function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the second script section will execute before `$(document).ready` is fired. Thus it will be trying to attach the onclick handler to an element that doesn't exist yet.

You can make it work by either attaching the `click()` event to the element as you add it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<div/>', {
         id: 'foo',
         text: 'Does not work'
    })
    .appendTo('body')
    .click(function() {
       alert('Success');
    });       
});
```

or by using `on()`:

```
$('document').on("click", "#foo", function() {
  alert('Success');
});
```

Comment: You should note that using `$('#foo').on('click', ...)` is essentially the same as using `click()`. It will only work if the element *already exists* on the document.  
Use *delegation* by passing a selector to `on` so you don't have to attach it every time you create an element: `$(document).on('click', '#foo', ...)`. [See reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @GeReV Sorry about that, I'm still getting used to not using `live()`. I'll edit my answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta place all of that in a $(document).ready().

So:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('<div/>', {
                    id: 'foo',
                    text: 'Does not work'
                }).appendTo('body');       
                $("#foo").click(function () {
                alert('Success'); });
});
```